# Solve for time in constant velocity question (easy)

Tags: physics

A speeder drives by a cop car moving 50m/s. The cop takes 12 seconds to get things in order and then chases after the speeder, traveling 60 m/s. How much time will it take the cop to catch up to the speeder?

This is what I have so far:

$v_c= 60$ m/s

$x_c = 60(t-12)$

$v_s = 50$ m/s

$x_s = 50t$

I set the two equations equal to each other and I have

$$50t = 60(t-12)$$

$$t=72$$

However the solution says

$$60t = 600+50t$$

$$t=60$$

Why am I incorrect in my thinking? And shouldn't both methods of solving give the same answer?

Comment: Seems like there is maybe a typo. Maybe it was 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus on what's been asked in the question.

It's asked *How much time will it take for the cop to catch up to the speeder?*, not *after what time they meet or cross each other?*.

As it's given that the cop takes $12$ seconds to get things in order and he starts after that, we need to find the **time after the 12$^{th}$ second**. So you have time = $t_{\text{used by you }}-12 = 72-12 = 60$.

The time $t$ you've considered gives the total time after which they meet and you just need to subtract the $12$ seconds the cop took to get things in order in order to find the time taken by the cop to catch the speeder.

Comment: thank you so much! this was a great explanation. I realize my mistake now.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $t=60$ is correct. The speeder is $600$m ahead of the cop when he starts at $60$ meters per second. His speed relative to the speeder is $10$ meters per second so it takes $60$ seconds to catch the speeder.